# What does "the works of a watch" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The man slipped a long dark iron knife, almost a short sword, from his
>   belt, and after breathing on it, handed it hilt-first to Puck, who
>   took it with his head on one side, as you should when you look at
>   **the works of a watch**, squinted down the dark blade, and very delicately rubbed his forefinger from the point to the hilt.

This is from "Rewards and Fairies" "The Knife and Naked Chalk Hill" 
http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/digi300.pdf

I can't understand the meaning of " the works of a watch "
Is this just the movement of a watch?

I am glad if some one kindly teach me.

Comment: The "works" are the delicate and complicated moving parts inside an old-fashioned mechanical watch--the parts that make the watch work.

Answer (score 1):

> as you should when you look at the works of a watch,

Here "works" means ["clockwork"](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/clockwork).  Clockwork are small and precise and difficult to see, so you have to look at them very intently.

Comment: If it helps, the Japanese for this is 時計仕掛け.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and kind comment of Japanese so that i can understand it so clearly!

Answer (score 1):

The "works" are the delicate and complicated moving parts inside an old-fashioned mechanical watch--the parts that make the watch work.